# Importing .shp file into PostGIS with the function shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql, docker

I am trying to import a .shp file into PostgreSQL, but so far no success.
After completing the setup, I installed the PostGIS extension and finally went for some geo exploration. But, when I try to import a .shp file, this error appears:

```
root@e61fec68cbc2:/# shp2pgsql -s SRID br_shp_dir/BR_UF_2019.shp public.geo_br | psql -h localhost -d db-example -U postgres;
Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
SET
SET
BEGIN
ERROR:  relation "geo_br" already exists
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
ANALYZE

root@e61fec68cbc2:/#
```

I working Docker, so It's containerized.
I've done it before, but couldn't this time.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the command with -d switch https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage

> **-d**
>
> Drops the database table before creating a new table with the data in the Shape file.

for overwriting the table that you have created with your previous trials. The first error message tries to help `ERROR:  relation "geo_br" already exists`.

Comment: It worked!

I also had to install postgis again due to incomplete install for some reason, but your answer helped a lot. 

As soon as I am able to vote in GIS StackExchange, I come back here ;)
Thanks a lot.